# Enviar resultado de una operación en consola usando solo una clase en Java

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un fragmento de código donde por medio de una instancia de la clase en el método `main` se imprima el resultado en consola. Hace tiempo que no uso Java y he hecho como simple ejemplo el siguiente código, a partir de éste lo adaptaré a lo que necesito, con esto que llevo aún no me da el resultado en consola,necesito que quede en 1 sola clase y no en 2. Alguna sugerencia de lo que me falta?:

```
public class Suma {
//Atributos de la clase
int valor1, valor2, resultado;

//Constructor de la clase
Suma(int x, int y)
{
valor1=x;
valor2=y;
}

//Método de la clase
public void suma()
{
resultado=valor1+valor2;
System.out.println("El resultado es:" +resultado);
}
}


//Código de la clase PruebaSuma

public class PruebaSuma {
public static void main(String a[])
{
Suma s=new Suma(20,10);
s.suma();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solamente puedes tener una clase principal,  que use el metodo `main` este sera el primer metodo de la clase principal que se va a ejecutar,  si tienes otro main dentro de otra clase no estoy seguro si eso te de errores,  pero creo que confundirias al programa.

Sin embargo aquello que si se que pasaria es que uno de los dos metodos no se ejecutara automaticamente,  puesto que solo tu clase principal tiene el 'derecho' por decirlo asi a ejecutar este metodo de manera automatica,  en el resto de clases que uses un metodo `main` solo estarias definiendo en realidad un metodo comun y corriente que no se va a autoejecutar.

Estuve mas o menos 40 minutos pensando en que estaba pasando y el porque no te funcionaba...

Así que probe y probe y probe cosas y he aquí el resultado.

En primeras si quieres que la clase `Main` pueda hacer uso de tu clase `Suma`, hay dos opciones, pero solo voy a ondar en una puesto que la otra opción, no la he probado...

La primera opción que es la que no probe, es tener tu clase `Suma` en otro paquete dentro de tu paquete principal, e importarlo desde tu `package Main`, pero por ahora creo que no sería necesario enrollarnos con poner esa clase en otro paquete realmente...

La segunda opción es en el mismo paquete (en la misma carpeta), tener también tu archivo `Suma.java`.

Así que bien, primero explicare la estructura de carpetas que hice yo para que esto me funcionase:

```
prueba_java
   Main
      MainProc.java
      Suma.java
```

como vemos dentro de la carpeta llamada prueba_java se encuentra nuestra paquete principal (Main), y el archivo (root), del proyecto, dentro de este paquete `Main` tenemos los dos archivos juntos.

**Cabe aclarar que si tienes algun archivo .class dentro de tu proyecto, borralos, por que a mi no me actualizaba los .class a la hora de compilar.**

Teniendo esta estructura, tu código ahora se ve de la siguiente manera:

MainProc.java:

```
/*
  Como vemos referenciamos a nuestro paquete principal Main,
  si no lo referenciacemos podría ocurrir un error...
*/
package Main;

class MainProc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int val1 = 20;
        int val2 = 10; 
        //Creas y guardas tu instancia suma.
        Suma suma = new Suma();
    }
}
```

Suma.java:

```
/*
  Referenciamos al mismo paquete, puesto que ambas clases
  se encuentran en el mismo paquete (Main).
*/
package Main;

class Suma{ 

    Suma(){
       //Aquí dentro tenias errores en esta clase.
       int valor1, val1, val2, valor2, resultado;
       valor1 = val1 = valor2 = val2 = resultado = 0; 
       resultado = valor1 + valor2;
       System.out.println("El resultado es:" + resultado);
    }

}
```

Si bien esto en teoria podria funcionar, **NO LO HARA.**

Esto debido a que descubri algo muy estúpido que tiene el compilador **javac** de java, y es que si te encuentras en la misma ruta de tus archivos en la terminal (si te encuentras en el paquete Main), la compilación de la clase `Main` nunca funcionara, pero la de la clase `Suma` si lo hará.

Para solucionar esto toca hacer algo que me parece muy estúpido, y es cambiar a un directorio atrás e indicarle desde ese directorio los archivos a compilar, (recuerda haber eliminado de antemano los archivos .class que tuvieses).

Entonces supongamos que en la terminal nos encontramos en el package principal (`Main`), lo que deberíamos hacer es retornarnos una carpeta, entonces quedaríamos en la carpeta `prueba_java`:

```
prueba_java   //Aquí en la terminal
   Main       //Aquí no.
      MainProc.java
      Suma.java
```

Y una vez estemos en la carpeta prueba_java, primero debes compilar tus archivos .java de la siguiente manera (de lo contrario por alguna razón el estúpido compilador de java no compilara bien):

En la terminal digitarias primero:

```
javac Main/Suma.java
```

Y luego (la terminal no te debe decir nada), compilarias la clase `MainProc` así:

```
javac Main/MainProc.java
```

**Recuerda, antes de hacer esto asegurate de que no tengas archivos .class en la carpeta Main.**

Una vez compilados estos archivos, deberás **siempre** ejecutar tu archivo principal de esta manera en la terminal:

```
//Cuidado! no pongas la extensión al archivo o tendrás un error!
java Main/MainProc
```

Ahora debería funcionar...

La verdad es que entre `visual studio code` y `eclipse` o `netbeans` prefiero muchisimo mas a `eclipse`, ya que `visual studio code` no es un `IDE`, aunque si hablamos de solo `visual studio` ya es otra cosa...

El motivo de esto es que en `eclipse`, `netbeans` o `visual studio` (no el code), todo esto se facilita muchisimo mas, por ejemplo en `eclipse` o `netbeans` tu solo te encargas de crear las clases que desees y automaticamente estos `IDE` harán este trabajo por ti... y solo tendrias que preocuparte de lanzar la aplicación o programa con el botón de `play`.

Lo cuál es mucho mas sencillo que estar haciendo todo este proceso solo para poder ver nuestro programa en java...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Riven, el único detalle que ahora tengo es en el constructor, en la línea: int valor1=val1,valor2=val2,resultado=0; ya que mi compilador me marca el error: Cannot find Symbol. Alguna idea de a qué puede referirse?

Comment: Porque no tienes creada la clase y eso que hiciste no es una buena idea,  el contructor no deberia ir ahi,  debes generar la clase en el mismo paquete para poder usarala o importarla desde algun otro paquete en el que la tengas.

Comment: Es decir, a lo que me refiero es que seguro la tienes creada pero la tienes mal importada, mal formada,  o mal relacionada a la principal. o depronto nisiquiera la haz compilado.

Comment: Una pregunta, con que programa creaste las clases?

Comment: Estoy usando un pluggin de java en VS

Comment: Acabo de crear el código usando 2 clases, pero no me resulta, ahora debo dejarlo todo en una sola clase.

Comment: Visual studio code por defecto creo que no te ayuda con los classpaths... a lo mejor la referencia de la clase Suma no esta en ningun classpath,  que es el 'listado' por decirlo asi de las clases e importaciones que se realizan en los diferentes archivos que tengas,  y pues si alguna no esta en el classpath el codigo va a fallar...

Comment: @Jonsin, checa de nuevo la respuesta porfavor, acabo de modificarla y creo que ahora el programa te debería funcionar si sigues los pasos realizados en la respuesta, de verdad que te recomiendo mejor usar un IDE y no visual studio code... te ahorran bastante trabajo y comederos de cabeza...

Comment: Por cierto ten cuidado,  el codigo parece igual pero no es asi,  ahi en la respuesta tu Main.java lo puse como MainProc.java y dentro el nombre de la clase tambien cambio,  tenlo en cuenta... por que si no no te funcionaria... Aunque siempre y cuando hagas los cambios respectivos para adaptarlo a como tiene el nombre de tus archivos y clases, entonces debera funcionarte.